# How do I configure Fubu for a view without a controller?

Tags: fubumvc

I have an `Index` action on a controller that's not doing anything.

```
public EmptyModel Index()
{
     return null;
}
```

The `Index` view simply displays some html, with jQuery-driven ajax and the MasterPage doing all the heavy lifting on this particular page.  When I remove this action function from it's controller, the aspx view will no longer display.

---

### More Information and Update:

After making the changes mentioned in Chad's answer the url that used to return the index view now instead returns a 404.  This issue may exist because most of the views' folder structure is done in the early Fubu Framework style (with `View_Page_Type_Declarations.cs` and no code-behinds), rather than using the more intuitive and more recent default folder conventions.  But it's possible my analysis is off.

Here's my FubuRegistry:

```
public WebAppFubuRegistry()
{
    IncludeDiagnostics(true);

    Services(x => x.SetServiceIfNone<IWebAppSecurityContext, WebAppSecurityContext>());

    Applies.ToThisAssembly()
        .ToAssemblyContainingType<HomeController>();


    Actions
        .IncludeClassesSuffixedWithController();


    Routes
        .UrlPolicy<WebAppUrlPolicy>()
        .IgnoreControllerNamespaceEntirely()
        .ConstrainToHttpMethod(action => action.Method.Name.StartsWith("Perform"), "POST");


    Views
        .TryToAttach(x=> x.by<ViewAndActionInDifferentFolders>())
        .TryToAttachWithDefaultConventions()
        .RegisterActionLessViews(WebFormViewFacility.IsWebFormView,
               chain => chain.PartialOnly());

    /*Behavior Code */
}
```

WebAppUrlPolicy:

```
public class WebAppUrlPolicy : IUrlPolicy
    {
        public bool Matches(ActionCall call, IConfigurationObserver log)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public IRouteDefinition Build(ActionCall call)
        {
            if(call.IsForHomeController())
                return new RouteDefinition("home");

            if(call.IsAnIndexCall())
                return new RouteDefinition(call.ControllerPrefix());

            var otherRoute = new RouteDefinition(call.ToControllerActionRoute());

            return otherRoute;
        }
    }
```

ViewAndActionInDifferentFolders:

```
public class ViewAndActionInDifferentFolders : IViewsForActionFilter
    {
        public IEnumerable<IViewToken> Apply(ActionCall call, ViewBag views)
        {
            if (call.IsForHomeController())
            {
                var viewTokens = views.ViewsFor(call.OutputType()).Where(x => x.Name == "HomeIndexView");
                return new[] { new WebAppViewToken(call, viewTokens, "home") };
            }
            if (call.IsJsonCall())
            {
                return new List<IViewToken>();
            }
            return CreateSingleTokenList(call, views);
        }
        private static IEnumerable<WebAppViewToken> CreateSingleTokenList(ActionCall call, ViewBag views)
        {
            return new[] { new WebAppViewToken(call, views.ViewsFor(call.OutputType())) };
        }
    }
```

---

How do I reconfigure Fubu so that I can use a view without the action?

What changes need to be made to remove the action function above, and still maintain the same functionality?

Answer (score 3):

In your FubuRegistry, in the "Views" section, add:

`.RegisterActionLessViews(WebFormViewFacility.IsWebFormView, chain => chain.PartialOnly());`

For example, the whole views section may look like:

```
        Views
            .TryToAttachWithDefaultConventions()
            .RegisterActionLessViews(
                                        WebFormViewFacility.IsWebFormView, 
                                        chain => chain.PartialOnly());
```

Note that you can both ASPX and ASCX for headless views. If you only want ASCX files, then you can use `WebFormViewFacility.IsWebFormControl` instead.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, thanks for all the great answers.  For some reason when I make the changes you suggest the url can't find the view anymore.  I added some more detail to the question, and a few relevant files

Comment: I believe PartialOnly() means that you cannot view it in a browser -- only use it in partials.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

```
Views.RegisterActionLessViews(type => type.Name == "StaticView", 
       chain => chain.Route = new RouteDefinition("StaticView"));
```